# App name is not displayed in the list of application records in Xcode/iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, submission

I would like to ask regarding this issue that I have with iTunes Connect Submission. When I tried to submit my app to the iOS App Store via Organizer/Xcode, I couldn't find the application under the list of application records. Why is that so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I just edit/saved the application page and voila! the application name is now showing in the choices. Seems like Apple considered the failed binary as an already uploaded build.